# Why is the order of my features changed when using readFeatures in OpenLayers v4.6.5?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, features, mapping

I have a geojsonObject that is a featurecollection of X number of features.
see picture

[image: Featuers:]

I Then add this to a vector:

```
var Source = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject)
    });
```

I add this to a layer, and call a style function:

```
var Layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: Source,
        style: stylefcn(Source.getFeatures())
    });

function stylefcn(_features) {
console.log(_features)
//When i log my features here, the order of the features have changed. 
}
```

**Why does the order change?**

E.g: Feature number 0 from the picture above, has become feature number 4 in the style function.

(I have a small suspicion that this might happen when the number of features pass 10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [doc](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html):

> getFeatures():
>       Get all features on the source **in random order**.

Comment: Gee!
No quickFix then? I guess i need to tag all my features with a feature-id then? Or any suggestions for a good solution? :)

Comment: To be honest I don't know. I systematically assume to be getting items from a data source in an unpredictable and inconsistent order unless I have explicitly specified a sort order.

Answer (score 5):

To access features in order you would need a features collection:

```
var Source = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: new ol.Collection()
    });

Source.addFeatures(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject));

console.log(Source.getFeaturesCollection().getArray());
```

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks. Both answers are "correct" for my part. But JGH's answer is the answer to the "Heading questions. Not possible to accept both.

Comment: For me i found this solution to be the easiest one: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/5729 by using useSpatialIndex: false,